# Pendant light wiring

Tags: wiring, light

Trying to install a pendant light fixture. From the ceiling it’s 3 white wires 3 black wires and 3 copper total. 2 of the white are together 2 of the black are together and 1 white and 1 black are together. The light fixture has the standard 3 wires black white and green. How should I connect them?

Comment: How many light fixtures are controlled by that switch?

Answer (score 2):

This is assuming that the light switch also controls another light (or box where a light could be connected).

Connect the lights’s black wire to the two black wires (add the new wire to the other two, presumably in a wirenut). Do the same with the two white wires and the light’s white wire. Connect the green wire to the bundle of bare wires. Leave the black-to-white connection alone.

Where you are adding a wire to a bundle, do not remove any wires. All wires connected together must remain connected.

Details:
Hot comes in on the black wire connected to the white wire (which should be marked black with tape or paint). This is the switch loop hot to the switch. The black coming back on the same cable is the switched hot coming back from the switch.

This black is currently connected to a switched hot going to another light; you would connect the light’s hot there.

The cluster of white wires the neutral; you would connect the light’s neutral there.

The cluster of bare wires I’d safety ground; you would connect the light’s ground there.

Comment: This is correct if and only if the switch loop is wired correctly. As often as not they are not, so check back in if you find that the light is always on after following this advice. In general, always pay attention to how the old fixture was connected if the old fixture was working when your started replacing it, and install the new fixture the same way.